# ESLint does not find React Native components

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint

I'm getting these ESLint errors in all of my js files, which import React Native components. Imports from all other libraries work just fine and the app also compiles and runs without problems. Any idea what could be the reason?

```
  3:3  error  Text not found in 'react-native'        import/named
  4:3  error  View not found in 'react-native'        import/named
  5:3  error  ScrollView not found in 'react-native'  import/named
  6:3  error  StyleSheet not found in 'react-native'  import/named
```

Import:

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet 
} from 'react-native';
```

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.62.0",
"eslint": "6.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.8.1",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.0.0",
"flow-bin": "0.121.0" (not using in my code)
```

.eslintrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 7,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel",
    "react",
    "react-native",
    "import"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".native.js"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "keyword-spacing": [1, { "before": true }],
    "key-spacing": [1, { "afterColon": true }],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
    "react-native/no-unused-styles": 1,
    "react-native/split-platform-components": 2,
    "react-native/no-inline-styles": 0,
    "react-native/no-color-literals": 0,
    "consistent-return": 1,
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 1,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 1,
    "no-console": 0,
    "semi": [
      1,
      "always"
    ],
    "no-undef-init": 2,
    "no-undef": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": [1, {
      "vars": "all",
      "args": "after-used",
      "varsIgnorePattern": "hJSX",
      "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
    }],
    "no-var": 1,
    "eqeqeq": 1,
    "dot-notation": 1,
    "no-caller": 2,
    "no-eval": 2,
    "no-extend-native": 1,
    "no-implied-eval": 2,
    "no-shadow": [
      2,
      {
        "allow": [
          "err"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "quotes": [1, "single"],
    "no-multi-spaces": 1,
    "prefer-arrow-callback": 1,
    "import/default": 0,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": 1,
    "require-atomic-updates": 0,
    "space-infix-ops": 1,
    "space-unary-ops": 1,
    "comma-spacing": 1,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 1,
    "curly": 1
  },
  "globals": {
    "after": true,
    "afterEach": true,
    "before": true,
    "beforeEach": true,
    "describe": true,
    "xdescribe": true,
    "it": true,
    "xit": true,

    "fetch": true,
    "__DEV__": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

### It's a known issue

- You can track the problem on [react-native #28549](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28549)
- Also, I opened [a Github issue on eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1754) about this problem.

### Short explanation

Looking at `node_modules/react-native/index.js`, you can see that it uses [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to define all the exports.

```js
module.exports = {
  // Components
  get AccessibilityInfo(): AccessibilityInfo {
    return require('./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo');
  },
  get ActivityIndicator(): ActivityIndicator {
    return require('./Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator');
  },
  get Button(): Button {
    return require('./Libraries/Components/Button');
  },
```

This [interferes](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1754#issuecomment-626473480) with the linter's ability to statically resolve imports.

### Workaround

You can work around this issue by ignoring the entire react-native dependency in the eslint-plugin-import [import/ignore](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#importignore) setting:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/ignore": ["react-native"]
  }
}
```

Comment: A known issues as the github issue was created also by me :-D

Comment: As stated in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28549#issuecomment-657249702), ignoring "react-native" also ignores "react-native-svg" and co. Instead of "react-native" you can use ""node_modules/react-native/index\\.js$"" to target it explicitly