# Parse errors in imported module react-native

Tags: react-native, eslint, importerror, eslintrc

A friend and I are developing a small react-native app.
He recently included Es-lint and prettier to the project and I have an import error I have not been able to resolve since.

Any imports from react-native show the following error

> module
> "C:/Users/Brendan/projects/garden-manager-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index"
> Parse errors in imported module 'react-native': ';' expected.
> (14:32)eslintimport/namespace.

I have the following dependencies in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-camera": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-cli": "^5.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.1.4",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.28.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1283.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "4.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.1.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "~44.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-devtools-core": "4.14.0"
  }
```

My friend is not receiving this error on his end.

I cant seem to find much information on this particular problem but I have tried reinstalling the node_modules folder without any effect.

I know I can disable this rule to remove the error but would prefer to find a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint does not find React Native components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973737/eslint-does-not-find-react-native-components)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the convo at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28549#issuecomment-657249702

You should use this pattern as it will not match things like `react-native-navigation`.

```
  settings: {
    'import/ignore': ['node_modules/react-native/index\\.js$']
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

You might follow this thread: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28549

or temporary use:

```
settings: {
  'import/ignore': ['react-native'],
}
```

in your `eslintrc` file

Comment: That line of code is not ideal. The best solution in the link you provided is actually here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28549#issuecomment-657249702